# Unable to Print in Landscape Mode from Excel Document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, printer, printing

I'm encountering difficulty when attempting to print an Excel page in landscape mode. Despite trying various adjustments, such as scaling, changing paper formats, and playing with file and printer properties, I cannot successfully print the entire page in landscape orientation. All what it does is print the page in portrait mode. I even installed a new version of Windows, but the printing issue persists.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this problem, with a sole focus to solve only this printing issue from the ground up. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I've already experimented with changing custom scale, keeping paper format as A4, ensuring landscape mode is always selected, but none of these efforts have led to a successful print in landscape orientation.

Comment: More details required, I think: Which version of Windows? Which version of Excel? What printer? Is the printer driver the one for that printer?

Comment: There should be an Orientation box to change the orientation. Otherwise, did you click on "page setup" after all the drop down boxes in the print menu? It will take you to the page setup where you can select landscape.